# How to drop items while mass crafting instead of retaining them in 7 days to die?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

My problem is that I'm crafting items on a massive scale (for example 500 pieces of Stone Axes and my problem is that my inventory fills up since Stone Axes does not stack and it is really tedious to drop each item one by one.

How can I drop them automatically when my inventory fills up?

Comment: Won't new ones crafted be dropped to the ground automatically with a full inventory? I thought this was the case, but can't test it at the moment.

Comment: @TimS. Since A13 they are not anymore. The crafting queue stops when the inventory is full.

Comment: Gotcha, hadn't tried power crafting yet, but I can see how that'd be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is a little trick that can be done, it's does not auto drop the craft but if you craft like a lot of stone axe while you are walking around it is pretty usefull.

It's simple to use, you just have to fill up all your inventory, and put the item you are going to mass product on your tool belt. The everytime you see the message (or hear the sound) that the item is craft but can't be handle because you have no room, you just press the shortcut to drop it and it will be replace by the one you just crafted.

Answer (score 1):

There's no auto drop any more.

Two ways which I sometimes use to deal with excess:

1. Create chests, dump your excess into the chests with shift-click, and then destroy the chests
2. Use axes as fuel/input for your forge.  There's no shift-clicking here and it is quite onerous but it does still put the axe material to some practical use.  When I do this I find it's best to have one stack of something like iron fragments for the second input slot.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an AutoHotkey script that lets you rapidly drop items by ALT-Clicking on them.
It can be found here: https://7daystodie.com/forums/showthread.php?40946-Quick-Drop-script&p=428618#post428618